# Error while loading view in yii

Tags: yii, view

I yii beginner, I change the default controller from main.php in config and create new controller as follow,

```
 class HomeController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('newindex');
    }
}
```

newindex view is in site folder in view. But when i run this, its giving error HomeController cannot find the requested view "newindex". Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like below:

```
$this->render('//site/newindex');  //means views/site/newIndex.php
```

`//` refers to `Views` path. But when you say `$this->render('newIndex')` yii looks for `newIndex` file in `views/home/newIndex` which is given from controller name.